# Prove that a matrix is symplectic?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $\omega$ be the skew-symmetric bilinear form on $R^{2n}$ given by
$$\omega(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}y_{n+j}-x_{n+j}y_{j})$$
Let $\Omega$ be the $2n \times 2n$ matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & I_{n}\\
-I_{n} & 0
\end{pmatrix}
show that for all $x,y\in R^{2n}$, we have $\omega(x,y)=\langle x,\Omega y\rangle $
and a $2n \times 2n $ matrix A belong to Sp(n;R) iff $$-\Omega A^{tr}\Omega=A^{-1}.$$
First Part:
\begin{align}
\langle x,\Omega y\rangle &=\langle \{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{2n}\}, \Omega \{y_{1},y_{2},...y_{2n}\}\rangle \\
&=\langle \{x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{2n}\},\{y_{n+1},...y_{2n},-y_{1}...-y_{n}\}\rangle \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(x_{j}y_{n+j}-x_{n+j}y_{j})\\
&=\omega(x,y).
\end{align}
second part: A matrix will be in real symplectic group iff $\omega(Ax,Ay)=\omega(x,y)$. so
$$\langle Ax,\Omega Ay\rangle =\langle x,\Omega y\rangle \Rightarrow \langle A^{tr}\Omega^{tr}Ax,y\rangle =\langle \Omega^{tr}x,y\rangle \Rightarrow\Omega^{-tr}A^{tr}\Omega^{tr}=A^{-1}.$$
But $\Omega^{tr}\neq\Omega.$ Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Is not $\Omega^{tr}=\Omega^{-1}=-\Omega$, and all that's still needed follows from that?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg great!!! I had to go through a paper to prove the inverse equality. Thanks, I got the answer. is my proof so far correct? just asking

Comment: Seems good, although depending on how familiar we are with such implications, I might ask for justification of the very last implication: There, you basically say that if we have two matrices $C,D$ such that $\langle Cx, y\rangle = \langle Dx,y \rangle$ for *all* vectors $x,y$, then $C=D$. That is true, but do you know why it is true?